# Use Capistrano for Rake tasks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, capistrano

Is Capistrano only used for deploying Rails apps?

Basically I want a scripting framework to handle all server/client scripting for me.

Examples:

- Updating Ubuntu, installing gems with dependencies etc.
- Creating a new Rails app, Git initialize it and commit, create Heroku project and upload the app.
- Automatize basic file/folder operations

Should I consider to use Capistrano for this (cause it can handle server/clients) or should I just use Rake for it?

Capistrano could do everything Rake could, but not the other way around?

What are the pros and cons with each?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few attempts have been made at making capistrano more universal - [capistrano-boss](http://github.com/ascarter/capistrano-boss) and my own [capistrano-provisioning](http://github.com/setfire/capistrano-provisioning), for example - it may be that somebody has already done it. Certainly, in terms of running commands remotely and organising tasks, namespaces, hooks etc, capistrano is second-to-none. But I've yet to see a comprehensive solution that allows you to really administer remote systems using it.

Have you investigated [chef](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Home)? It seems that this is frequently used in conjunction with cap. 37signals, for example, have extensive chef [recipes](http://github.com/37signals/37s_cookbooks) available - and they were also the source of capistrano.